# .NET C# how to make version more readable automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, version-control

I will start from example: I have an version of my app which looks like this 
   **1.0.3450.26573**  (it is hard to read and looks nasty). Code to take this version is:

```
String Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

I want to see version **1.0.12**, **1.0.13**, **1.0.14** where 1.0.[BUILD], where BUILD is auto increasing on each build.

**How can I do this in a best way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, revision number would be great, but how I can get it, I use [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/).

Comment: Vault Plug-in for CruiseControl.NET

http://download-us.sourcegear.com/Vault/4.1.4.18402/CCNetPlugin.zip

Answer (score 1):

Actually, build number will not do you any good unless you'll be able to track which build number corresponds to which version of source code your application was built from. Rather, consider using revision number from your repository (if your SCM tool is anything similar to Subversion; to do so try [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re57.html)).

Answer (score 1):

[Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/versioningcontrolledbuild.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate that with your build environment. For us, CruiseControl.net increments the version number on each build. But you could also use a SVN revision number etc. There are several possibilities.

If you only want 3 digits instead of 4, you have to format the string yourself.